# What machines included in Bizspark?

Tags: bizspark

Can I create one A4 maschine(8 cores and 14 RAM), and two A0 machines(1 core, 768RAM). They can be turned on in the same time.

What if I create another A4 machine, but keep it turned off and turn it on alternately with another A4(keep working only one). Is it out of bizspark subscription and will be subscription blocked?

Best ragards, 
Gennady

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft subscription policy.

Comment: Hi! Yes, it's about microsoft bizspark subsriptions. I didn't find the information and there is no "Bizspark forum" so I asked here

Comment: Let's hope you find a forum for any itchy rashes you may have, as I fear they'll be off-topic too.

Comment: Poldie)) Thank for Your hopes!)

Answer (score 0):

1) Sorry for off-top, I'm a newbie at stackoverflow

2) I think I found an answer. For subscription there is allowed 20 cores. Virtual machines use cores like in a table below

[image]

So I think I can create another A4, as it will be 8+8+1+1, less then 20, allowed by bizspark subscription.

Best regards, 
Gennady